# Android: Load image into notification using Glide does'nt work properly

Tags: android

My app show notifications of style `MediaPlayer` with 3 actions play, previous, next.

In this notification I display the image of the music that I get via a URL, and I set `setLargeIcon(bitmap)`.

When I am in the background or the phone is locked and I click on the next or previous button of the notification, the notification is replaced by the new one with the title of the music, but the image does not load.

When the app is in foreground, and I change the music via the notification, the current notification is replaced by a new one with the music title and the image and it works fine.

So the code is called correctly but the image is not loaded by Glide in the background.

How do I make sure that the image is loaded when I am in the background?

Here is the code I use before creating the notification:

```
Glide.with(context).asBitmap().placeholder(Drawables.placeholder).load(music.imageURL).into(object: CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
    override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
        displayNotification(context, music, resource) //Displaying notification that setLargeIcon
    }

    override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {}
})
```

Is it possible to load an image via Glide when the application is in the background, or do I have to use another way and which one?

Comment: I have used Picasso to load image from url in Notification. Its working fine

Comment: It also works if the application is in the background?

Comment: yes i have used this for push notification. Even if app is not working, it will load the picture

Comment: I opted for Picasso because it works, apparently Glide should only work in foreground. Maybe we can adjust it for the background but I don't know how ..